# Remove header in iwd one page checkout

Tags: layout, header, layout-update

trying to remove the header at the final checkout page using iwd one page checkout extension.
In iwd_opc.xml I added

```
<remove name="footer"/>
```

below

```
<opc_index_index translate="label">

<label>Onepage Checkout</label>
```

But when I do the same with `<remove name="header"/>` all the the page goes blank.

How can I remove the header, or at least the menu? Thank you!

Comment: <default><remove name="footer"/></defaut>  try this

Comment: header or footer you need to remove ?

Comment: Sorry mixed up the text. I am able to remove the footer with my code. But same code for the header does not work. Then everything goes blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your themes local.xml please use

```
<opc_index_index>
<remove name="footer"/>
</opc_index_index>
```

for header try to remove following

```
<opc_index_index>
    <reference name="header">
        <remove name="top.search" />
        <remove name="top.links" />
        <remove name="top.menu" />
    </reference>
</opc_index_index>
```

Comment: Sorry mixed up the text. I am able to remove the footer with my code. But same code for the header does not work. Then everything goes blank.

Comment: for removing footer use my code

Comment: footer works fine. Problem is with the header :(

Comment: check my updated answer